# Android accounts restriction

Tags: android

I've developed an app with an AccountAuthenticator service.
So, I can create a specific account link to my app.

I'm facing the following issue. When I create a new contact, I can link this contact to my specific account. But I don't want my specific account could be linked to a contact.

I think it's possible.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand.

You want to "create" a new contact. You're not allowed to create contacts, only **raw contacts**. If you add a raw contact that doesn't seem to be related to an existing contact, the Contacts Provider will add a contact for you.

A contact is an aggregation of individual raw contacts that have similar or identical names. A raw contact represents a person's name for a particular account name and account type. To add a raw contact, you *must* provide an account type and account name. An account type represents a set of accounts related by domain; it can also represent a web server domain and a sync adapter (if you want). The account name is one account for the domain.

It's not *your* account name or the *raw contact's* that's being linked to the contact, it's the *user's*. Having an account name and type for each raw contact ensures that the Contacts Provider can correctly sync information to servers such as Google Contacts.

You can create your own account type and account name and authenticate with the AccountAuthenticator service if you want, or you can authenticate the user's information, but that has nothing to do with contacts. You can create a raw contact with an account name and type that aren't authenticated; the account name and type don't have to exist anywhere. They just have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, I have an account which have a unique account type linked to my app.

In general, when you create an phone contact, you can link the contact to your Google account.
So, I don't want the account "linked" to my app appears in the accounts list which can be linked to a phone contact.